# IIS ARR Error 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, arr

I have an ARR IIS with a server farm that contains only one server.
the site has http and https binding. SSL certificate which installed on both ARR and content server are same and imported and also installed in mmc.
when I browse that site with `https` protocol, I receive error `502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server`, but `http` protocol works fine. What may cause this problem and how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I will post the solution for whom may have the same issue in future, you have to pick IP Address of ARR in IIS site binding. 
so it should look like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 instead of *.443